# How can I fix maps for Warcraft 3 Reforged

Tags: warcraft-3

I've been playing a bit of Warcraft 3 recently, mostly because there's enough players now that custom maps which aren't DoTA actually get players. I have one which I was looking forward to playing again, but unfortunately in the new Reforged client, it doesn't work.

When you try to host with the map, you immediately leave the lobby, but are left looking at the lobby with just one slot in it.

The map isn't so much "protected" as "it was never written with the world editor in the first place", as near as I can tell.

I'm a software developer by trade so I don't mind getting my hands dirty in JASS or whatever if that's required, but I don't really know anything about the system to begin with.

What can I do to fix the map for Reforged?

Comment: Feels bad that they did that to our beloved Warcraft ...